# To encrypt or install security app like Prey?

Tags: encryption, prey

I have just bought an Android tablet and would like advice as to whether I should encrypt it or install some security app like Prey.

If I encrypt it, then if it is stolen the thief won't be able to access it and so could just reset it to factory settings. In this case my data would be secure but I'd have no hope of getting the tablet back. On the other, if I don't encrypt it then the thief might not factory reset the tablet and so an installed security app like Prey could be used to track the tablet and there would be some hope of getting the tablet back at the risk of perhaps exposing my data.

Are these my only two choices or is there something else that can be done to secure data AND have some hope of retreiving the tablet?

Comment: I'd guess most thieves would wipe it even if it wasn't encrypted unless you didn't have a lockscreen or anything.  I like the solution below that will survive a wipe.

Comment: Simplest solution of all, is, well, keep a close eye on the tablet, but considering the mass influx of tablets on the market, do not think anyone would want to steal it! Furthermore, Prey/Cerberus, in order to be extremely useful, does need 3G in order to be able to call the number if stolen so may not be as quite as useful for tablets.

Answer (score 1):

The [Cerberus](http://www.cerberusapp.com) app allows you to remotely track and wipe your Android device, as well as a lot more.

If you have root, you can install it as a system app, and it will survive a wipe - which is really handy, it can also be hidden from the app drawer.

I believe that this app will be the most use to you.

Please not that I am not affiliated with Cerberus at all, and am just a customer.